# Cannot read property 'trustAsHtml' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive below that calls a function called onGetJson().

However whenever it runs I get an error in the console that says

[image]

The object scope.json is a valid JSON object with data inside.

What adjustments do I need to make?

```
    class GoogleJob {
    constructor(scope, $sce, $filter) {
        'ngInject';
        let directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: function () {
                return '<script type="application/ld+json" ng-bind-html="onGetJson()"></script>';
            },
            scope: {
                json: '='
            },
            replace: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, $sce, $filter) {
            scope.onGetJson = function () {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml($filter('json')(scope.json));
            };
          }
       };

        return directive;
    }
}
export default GoogleJob;
```

Comment: Remove $sce and $filter from link function and remove scope from constructor function

Comment: Thanks for the support. Just tried it. Same error :(

Comment: What code do you have at line 15 of your directive ?